# Proof of correctness of RSA sufficient?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

In a lecture I am taking the following proof for the RSA cryptosystem is given:
$m^{ed} \equiv m^{ee^{-1}} \equiv m^1 \equiv m \pmod N$

where $N = pq$; $p$,$q$ prime; $2 < e < \phi(N)$; $e$,$\phi(N)$ coprime; and $d$ is chosen so that $ed \equiv 1 \mod \phi(N)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

The equation in the first line is the complete proof presented. Nothing else is given. In particular, $m$ is NOT required to be coprime to $N$. My question is:
Is this a sufficient proof? The typical proofs for RSA are much longer and invoke either Euler's, Fermat's or the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

My analysis is that it is not obvious that we should be allowed to consider the exponent as a number $\mod {\phi(N)}$ unless that is separately proven to be valid. As far as I am aware, since $m$ and $N$ are not coprime, it's not necessarily true that $m^{\phi(N)} \equiv 1 \mod N$, thus we cannot simply take the exponent modulo $\phi$. Is there another way to see that this proof should be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\bmod n$ requires $\gcd(m,n)=1$, but $m^{\phi(n)+1}\equiv m\bmod n$ doesn't.

Comment: I see, for square-free N, this holds apparently. However, my question was supposed to be more of a question about whether one should consider this proof sufficiently justified or whether it assumes to many things that are not obvious (however true). But now it‘s closed so whatever. Thanks for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

wlog we need to prove: $m^{k \times \phi(N)+1} = m \mod N$.

If $m = \ell p q$ then the above is true since $0 = 0 \mod N$.

Hence wlog $m = p \ell$ where $(\ell,pq) = (\ell,N) = 1$.

Now by Fermat's little theorem,:

$$m^{k \times \phi(N)+1} = p^{k \times \phi(N)+1} \times \ell^{k \times \phi(N)+1} = p^{k \times \phi(N)+1} \times \ell \mod pq$$

Hence it suffices to prove $$p^{k \times \phi(N)+1}  = p\mod pq$$

$$\implies p^{k \times \phi(N)+1}-p  = (p^{k \times (p-1)(q-1)} - 1) \times p \mod pq$$

Again By Fermat's little theorem : $p^{k \times (p-1)(q-1)} - 1 = 0 \mod q \implies p^{k \times (p-1)(q-1)} - 1 \ is \ a \ multiple \ of \ q$.

Hence, $$(p^{k \times (p-1)(q-1)} - 1) \times p  = 0 \mod pq$$

Hence,  $$p^{k \times (p-1)(q-1)+1} = p \mod pq$$

Hence, $$p^{k \times \phi(N)+1} = p \mod pq$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware of the common proofs for RSA. My question is more about whether the presented proof in the OP is sufficient or whether it assumes to many non-trivial things without mentioning them first.

Comment: @JMC My proof says that the presented proof is sufficient as I consider the case when $m$ and $N$ are not co-prime.

Comment: Your proof is a proof of the lecture's statement. That doesn't make the lecture's statement a sufficient proof of RSA in and of itself, where by "sufficient" I mean "comprehensible without assuming other previously unmentioned, non-trivial lemmas pr proofs such as yours." Your proof, or anything similar to it, was completely omitted from the lecture. So yes, you show that it's a correct statement, but that wasn't the question. The question is rather: can just stating the statement without any other proof be itself considered a valid proof of RSA or does it make too many hidden assumptions?